# What does it mean when a region is described as "Dangerous"?

Tags: moon-hunters

On the world map, when selecting a stage, some stages are marked with a monster claw and described as "Dangerous". What does this mean? What manner of horrors - and accompanying rewards! - await me in such areas?

[image: Dangerous!]

Comment: As far as I know it assures at least one Arena and lots of "great" monsters like lions and stuff like that.